# How to get rid of a dynamic chat dialogue in web page by using coded UI

Tags: c#, automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm wondering how I can solve the following issue. In a web application, which I suppose to automate by using Coded UI, there is a dynamic chat dialogue, which appears after some random time and swims from right to left edge. Since it moves, it hides some controls and will interfere with the automated test and causing the test to fail. Do you have any idea how I should get rid of it?

Since it moves, it doesn't have a fix position.

I thought, I may need to come up with a new thread and monitor the whole web application. As soon as it appears, I need to kill the chat dialogue box. This may work in theory but I'm not sure whether it works in the reality. Even if it works, it will be very costly and not easy solution.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? If yes, can you please share your solution?

Comment: Can you capture the chat dialogue using the coded ui crosshairs? It's possible you could have some sort of mechanism to watch for it and close it if you can get it's search properties.

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI works by searching for controls not by knowing their position on the screen. Hence a normal usage of Coded UI should work fine on your application. Consider using the `WaitForControlExist` or possibly the other `WaitForControl...` methods to deal with the dialogue that appears after an unknown time interval.

Comment: Thx. It is clear to me that searching is not based on position. However the problem is that the Coded UI test builder tool can not record and recognize the floating chat dialogue. That is the reason, why I mentioned the position in my previous message. Sorry that was my bad.